# Serving images from AWS S3

Tags: javascript, node.js, angularjs, amazon-s3

I am having an issue that I cant solve in my head for some reason. 
I have a client (Angular) and server (Node). They should run in same domain.

Idea is that when the user is logged in he can change his profile image and store it DB.

Angular client (which is SPA) is served by Apache, however Angular talks to Node.js which runs on different port, but they are running on the same instance.

So, user changes the image which is save on S3 and the link to the image is stored in users DB. When the user is logged in, his image will be shown on the page.

Is there a flow with this design?

Comment: Have you actually tried to build this? Or are you looking for design suggestions? If the latter, you might find more help on Programmers.SE provided you expand your question (see http://programmers.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic)

Comment: I have this built, and ut works. Only way how i can display images wuth this structure is to make bucket public and display it like this... <img src="http://s3.amazonaws.com/mybucket/myfile.jpg"  ... ></img>

Comment: Is it good degisn to make this bucket public, accessible by direct linking?

Comment: You will need to make bucket public or use CF and use s3 bucket as your origin.